# React Navigation: StackNavigator transition for Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I am using this library https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/ to build android by react-native. I can make the navigation happens on android device but how I can make the screen slide in from the right and fade in from the left. It seems that this behaviour happens on iOS device but not in Android. Is there any animation configuration for android app?

Please see below animation. This is recorded in iOS.

[image]

Answer (score 30):

Starting from : "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",

```
import {createStackNavigator, TransitionPresets} from '@react-navigation/stack';


const TransitionScreenOptions = {
  ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS, // This is where the transition happens
};

const CreditStack = createStackNavigator();

function CreditStackScreen() {
  return (
    <CreditStack.Navigator screenOptions={TransitionScreenOptions}> // Don't forget the screen options
      <CreditStack.Screen
        name="Credit"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={headerWithLogo}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="WorkerDetails"
        component={WorkerDetails}
        options={headerWithLogoAndBackBtn}
      />
    </CreditStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

You can watch this video to understand more:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvjV96CNPqM&ab_channel=UnsureProgrammer

Comment: It will not work if you follow the last react-navigation docs (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation) because you will end up using createNativeStackNavigator, not createStackNavigator: the difference is that many of the options your can pass to the latter cannot be passed to the former. In that case you can pass presentation:"card" and animation: 'slide_from_right' in your Navigator's screenOptions prop

Comment: @Apperside Thank you for the information. I've added the version when I wrote this to avoid conflicts. Can you please add what you wrote as an answer so people can find it in the future? Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Mohamed, I've added an answer with an in-depth explanation

Answer (score 22):

You should use `transitionConfig` to override default screen transitions as written [on this page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig).

Unfortunately there is no example provided how that function works but you can find some examples in this file: `\react-navigation\lib\views\CardStackStyleInterpolator.js`

So your code should look like this:

```
 const navigator = StackNavigator(scenes, {
transitionConfig: () => ({
    screenInterpolator: sceneProps => {
        const { layout, position, scene } = sceneProps;
        const { index } = scene;

        const translateX = position.interpolate({
            inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
            outputRange: [layout.initWidth, 0, 0]
        });

        const opacity = position.interpolate({
            inputRange: [
                index - 1,
                index - 0.99,
                index,
                index + 0.99,
                index + 1
            ],
            outputRange: [0, 1, 1, 0.3, 0]
        });

        return { opacity, transform: [{ translateX }] };
    }
})
});
```

Comment: Be careful: If you follow the getting started guide of react-navigation's docs, you will end up using NativeStackNavigator (and not StackNavigator) and transitionConfig will not work in that case. I've explained the problem in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74739666/997716

Answer (score 9):

For StackNavigatoin 6.x.x

Just import

```
import { TransitionPresets } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

Then create a config:

```
const screenOptionStyle = {
  // headerShown: false,  
  ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
};
```

And finally just assign them to the Stack Navigator Screen Options:

```
<Stack.Navigator 
     screenOptions={screenOptionStyle}
    > 

      <Stack.Screen 
      ...
      ...
```

Comment: it will not work if you are using createNativeStackNavigator instead of createStackNavigator. If you are following the official docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation most probably you will end up using the former, which does not accept many of the options accepted by the latter. In that case you can pass presentation:"card" and animation: 'slide_from_right' in your Navigator's screenOptions prop

Answer (score 7):

All the above answers are correct, but the solutions work **ONLY** if you are using [createStackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/), and not if you are using [createNativeStackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#api-definition); unfortunatelly, if you are following the get started section from react-navigation's docs, you will end up using the latter.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69064284/997716) you can find a SO question speaking about the differences between the two, but the most relevant one for this questions is that many of the options that your can pass to the former (such as `transitionConfig`), cannot be passed to the latter.

If you are using `createNativeStackNavigator` this is how you can do it:

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'

const StackNavigator = createNativeStackNavigator()

const MyNativeStackNavigator = () =>{
    
    return  <StackNavigator.Navigation
        screenOptions={{
          animation: 'slide_from_right', //<-- this is what will do the trick
          presentation: 'card',
        }}
      >
        {routes}
      </StackNavigator.Navigator>

}
```

Comment: This is correct, however, it doesn't provide the "fade" effect on Android like it does on iOS. It only slides from right without any fade transition (on Android).

Answer (score 3):

you need to import StackViewTransitionConfigs from 'react-navigation-stack'
then, override the transitionConfing function.

```
const myStack = createStackNavigator({
    Screen1,
    Screen2,
    Screen3
},{
    transitionConfig: () => StackViewTransitionConfigs.SlideFromRightIOS
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On @react-navigation/stack component version, the way to do a slide from the right animation is:

```
<Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
        cardStyleInterpolator: ({index, current, next, layouts: {screen}}) => {
            const translateX = current.progress.interpolate({
                inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
                outputRange: [screen.width, 0, 0],
            });

            const opacity = next?.progress.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
                outputRange: [1, 0, 0],
            });

            return {cardStyle: {opacity, transform: [{translateX}]}};
        },
    }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={MainScreen} />
    ...
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use options and set the animation to 'slide_from_right'

Example:

```
<Stack.Screen 
name="Screen" 
component={Screen} 
options={{animation: 'slide_from_right'}} >
</Stack.Screen>
```

PS - The default animation for ios is slide_from_right (same)

but the default for Android is the fade effect which can be changed

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use the react native [navigation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html) for this. You can configure your screen using **configureScene** method. Inside that method use **Navigator.SceneConfigs** for animating screen. It's work for both android and iOS.

Comment: Are you talking about `https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack` this page? I didn't find Navigator.SceneConfigs related settings.

Comment: Navigator from `react-navite` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get useful information from `index.d.ts` file, find the `export interface TransitionConfig` , then press 'Ctrl' & left_click on `NavigationTransitionSpec` and `NavigationSceneRendererProps`, then you can get everything you want.