# Unable to render navigation screen using react native navigation, stack navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application, react-navigation-v6

I want to navigate in react navigation with my custom side nav bar(Not using drawerNavigator for this). I have placed the side nav bar and bottom bar fixed in app.js as it will be present in all screens. The middle content area should be loaded as per button click on side nav bar.

[image: Screen Layout]

From the docs, im following Navigation without navigation prop https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop. I have followed this tutorial , the screen is not visible on button click.

**App.js**

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.app}>
          <View style={styles.navDrawer}>
            <SideNav></SideNav>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
              <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="HomeScreen"
                  component={HomeScreenComponent}
                />
              </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
            {/* <Text style={styles.titleText}>DEMO</Text>
              <Text>STATUS:{this.state.status}</Text>
              <Text>{this.state.message}</Text>
              <Text>Is connected to wifi :{this.state.isWifi}</Text>
              <Text>
              Is Internet Reachable {this.state.isInternetReachable}
              </Text>
              <Button title="Exit lock task" onPress={this.handleLockTask} />
              <Button
              title="Remove device owner"
              onPress={this.handleRemoveDeviceOwner}
            /> */}
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.bottom}>
          <BottomBar
            roverStatus={this.state.status}
            serverStatus={this.state.isInternetReachable}></BottomBar>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 5,
  },
  app: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#121212',
  },
  navDrawer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  content: {
    flex: 9,
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: '#121212',
  },
  sideContent: {
    flex: 2,
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
  },
  bottom: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#121212',
  },
});
```

**RootNavigation.js**

```
export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef();
/**To Navigate */
export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```

**sideNav.js**

```
export default class SideNav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.menuIcon}
          onPress={() => {
            console.log(RootNavigation.navigationRef.current.getRootState());
            RootNavigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {test: 'hi'});
          }}>
          <Svg height={50} width={55}>
            <HomeSvgIcon></HomeSvgIcon>
          </Svg>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.menuIcon}>
          <Svg height={50} width={55}>
            <RoutesSvgIcon></RoutesSvgIcon>
          </Svg>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.menuIcon}>
          <Svg height={50} width={55}>
            <JobsSvgIcon></JobsSvgIcon>
          </Svg>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.menuIcon}>
          <Svg height={50} width={55}>
            <CalendarSvgIcon></CalendarSvgIcon>
          </Svg>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.menuIcon}>
          <Svg height={50} width={55}>
            <HistorySvgIcon></HistorySvgIcon>
          </Svg>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.menuIcon}>
          <Svg height={50} width={55}>
            <InfoSvgIcon></InfoSvgIcon>
          </Svg>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
  },
  menuIcon: {
    // flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    opacity: 1,
    borderColor: '#BCBCBC',
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10,
  },
  text: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
  },
});
```

**Edit: Notices with console logs in render method, component is being rendered but its not visible on screen**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: The problem was in the style property: `alignItems: 'center'`. When that was taken away, navigation began working again.

I would first confirm that your custom made navigator works with native-stack. Native stack uses the OS' navigation to navigate between pages. The issue may lie in your custom navigator and the OS' native navigator to be in conflict.

Consider using `@react-navigation/stack` here to see if this changes the behavior of your navigation.

Here is a relevant post for you to [browse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69064126/what-is-the-difference-between-react-navigation-stack-vs-react-navigation-nati).
Here is the documentation on [stack-navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator).

Comment: Changed to Stack Navigator, but the issue was with one of the style properties which didnot display the content. alignIntems :'center'. Donot know why it was not working with navigation container, it worked without the navigation container though.

Comment: Okay awesome, I am glad you figured it out. I edited my answer so other users with the same problem may see it.